# Relation for angles between 3 unit vectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let there be $3$ unit vectors $\textbf{a}_1,\textbf{a}_2,\textbf{a}_3$ in $3\text{D}$. If we have 
$$\textbf{a}_1\cdot\textbf{a}_2=p$$ $$\textbf{a}_2\cdot\textbf{a}_3=q$$ $$\textbf{a}_1\cdot\textbf{a}_3=r$$
how do we find $p$ in terms of $q$ and $r$?

Comment: there is nothing except a triangle inequality for the great circle arcs joining these on the unit sphere. If you then include the vertex angles for that triangle, you get a law of sines and two laws of cosines, all under "spherical trigonometry." There is also, then, the first case of the Gauss Bonnet Theorem, which gives the area of the triangle

Comment: What type of relationship are you looking for?

Comment: @memerson $p=f(q,r)$.

Comment: @WillJagy So there is no relation of the form $F(p,q,r)=0$?

Comment: No; you can keep $q,r$ fixed and vary $p,$ by changing the angle at that vertex.

Comment: Requiring a solution means that p, q and r are in same plane